# Simplifying the invocation of functions stored inside an ReaderT environment

Tags: haskell, rio

Let's assume I have an environment record like this:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

type RIO env a = ReaderT env IO a

data Env = Env
  { foo :: Int -> String -> RIO Env (),
    bar :: Int -> RIO Env Int
  }

env :: Env
env =
  Env
    { foo = \_ _ -> do
        liftIO $ putStrLn "foo",
      bar = \_ -> do
        liftIO $ putStrLn "bar"
        return 5
    }
```

The functions stored in the environment might have different number of arguments, but they will always produce values in the `RIO Env` monad, that is, in a `ReaderT` over `IO` parameterized by the environment itself.

I would like to have a succinct way of invoking these functions while inside the `RIO Env` monad.

I could write something like this `call` function:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader 

call :: MonadReader env m => (env -> f) -> (f -> m r) -> m r
call getter execute = do
  f <- asks getter
  execute f
```

And use it like this (possibly in combination with [`-XBlockArguments`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=blockarguments#extension-BlockArguments)):

```
 example1 :: RIO Env ()
 example1 = call foo $ \f -> f 0 "fooarg"
```

But, ideally, I would like to have a version of `call` which allowed the following more direct syntax, and still worked for functions with a different number of parameters:

```
 example2 :: RIO Env ()
 example2 = call foo 0 "fooarg"

 example3 :: RIO Env Int
 example3 = call bar 3
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the two examples, we can guess that `call` would have type `(Env -> r) -> r`.

```hs
example2 :: RIO Env ()
example2 = call foo 0 "fooarg"

example3 :: RIO Env Int
example3 = call bar 3
```

Put that in a type class, and consider two cases, `r` is an arrow `a -> r'`, or `r` is an `RIO Env r'`. Implementing variadics with type classes is generally frowned upon because of how fragile they are, but it works well here because the `RIO` type provides a natural base case, and everything is directed by the types of the accessors (so type inference isn't in the way).

```hs
class Call r where
  call :: (Env -> r) -> r

instance Call r => Call (a -> r) where
  call f x = call (\env -> f env x)

instance Call (RIO Env r') where
  call f = ask >>= f
```

Comment: You can avoid `FlexibleInstances` and probably improve typed hole messages by using `instance e ~ Env => Call (RIO e r)`.

Comment: Or better, do use `FlexibleInstances` but improve the class. `class e ~ TheEnv r => Call e r where type TheEnv r; call :: (e -> r) -> r`, and so on. `IO` doesn't have to be fixed either; `ReaderT e ' m r` works just fine with a `Monad m` instance constraint.

Comment: I've toyed a bit more with this solution here https://github.com/danidiaz/moo-nad

Comment: Related functional pearl: "The Decorator Pattern in Haskell" http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~ntc2/haskell-decorator-paper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few minor improvements on Li-yao's answer. This version isn't specific to `IO` as the base monad, or to `Env` as the environment type. Using an equality constraint in the base case instance should improve type inference a tad, though as `call` is intended to be used that will probably only affect typed holes.

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class e ~ TheEnv r => Call e r where
  type TheEnv r
  call :: (e -> r) -> r

instance Call e r => Call e (a -> r) where
  type TheEnv (a -> r) = TheEnv r
  call f x = call (\env -> f env x)

instance (Monad m, e ~ e') => Call e (ReaderT e' m r) where
  type TheEnv (ReaderT e' m r) = e'
  call f = ask >>= f
```

The associated type is arguably overkill. It would also be possible to use a functional dependency:

```
{-# language FunctionalDependencies, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Call e r | r -> e where
  call :: (e -> r) -> r

instance Call e r => Call e (a -> r) where
  call f x = call (\env -> f env x)

instance (Monad m, e ~ e') => Call e (ReaderT e' m r) where
  call f = ask >>= f
```